# YII2.0 query for multiple database

Tags: php, mysql, database, yii2

I have two database in my application,and both database all the tables are same(Except user table, first database only have a user table) via the first database i made login.

For example : database1.test and database2.test, i have created the test model with the help of first database test table.

After login based on the user_type i have connected the DB.

### Code in user model:

```
public static function selectDb($user_type) {
        switch($user_type) {
            case 1:
                return Yii::$app->get('db2'); //database2
            case 0:
                return Yii::$app->get('db1'); //database1

        }
    }
```

so that now i make the connection with database2,and i write the query using test model

**My query :**

```
$model = \app\models\Test::find()->all();
```

empty result is showing in this query.

**My Test model**

```
class Test extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'tbl_test';
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\Connection the database connection used by this AR class.
     */
    public static function getDb()
    {
        return Yii::$app->get('db1');
    }





    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['id'], 'integer'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
        ];
    }
}
```

May i know how to get solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your code sample your `Test::getDb()` always gets the first database, it doesn't take into account the `$user_type` and therefore doesn't use the selected database.
Your `User::selectDb()` function returns the database you want to use but it doesn't alter any global state which would make it the default (and it shouldn't).

To fix your issue, the `Test::getDb()` method will have to be able to find the database selected by `User::selectDb()`.

If you're using a custom user account class that implements the `IdentityInterface` ([docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authentication.html#implementing-identity)), as I suspect you are, then you could add a method there like so to your `User` class;

```
/**
* @returns \yii\db\Connection
*/
public function getSelectedDb()
{
    return static::selectDb($this->user_type);
}
```

and then your `Test` class could look like the following:

```
/**
 * @return \yii\db\Connection gets a connection to the database for the current user type.
 */
public static function getDb()
{
    /** @var app\models\User */
    $user = Yii::$app->user;
    return $user->getSelectedDb();
}
```

You might want to extend on this last piece of code to ensure it also works if `$user` is `null` (e.g. `return $user ? $user->getSelectedDb() : Yii::$app->get('db1')`). This can happen if the user isn't logged in.